# Как получить значение выбранного <option> из выпадающего списка и отправить его в сервлет?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl, html-select

Есть `select` сгенерированный на сервере. Он находится в форме с другими инпутами, которые post запросом вернутся на сервер.

```
<select class="selectpicker" id ="loc" name ="loc">
<c:forEach items="<%=CourseLocation.values()%>" var="location">
<option value = "${location.name()}">${location.toString()}</option>
</c:forEach></select><br/>
```

Я не могу уловить суть. Когда я на странице выбираю один из вариантов, его `option` становиться `selected` автоматически или нужен какой то скрипт присваивающий этому `option` значение `selected`?

Так же, как я понимаю `select` в отличие от `input` не может напрямую отправить ответ на сервер? Необходимо ли мне создавать отдельный `input type="hidden"` и в его передавать значение из `option`?

И третий вопрос. Я использую jsp страницы с jstl. Достаточно ли этого для реализации моей задачи, или необходимо использовать js? Как это реализовать через jstl или js.

Comment: Автоматически становится selected, но это не значение, а признак. Select отправляется на сервер наравне с input со значением из value. loc=название_локейшена. js не нужен для такой тривиальной задачи. https://webref.ru/html/select

Comment: тоесть на сервере я должен ловить loc? Они придет стрингом или ENUM как я его сюда и вставлял?

Comment: Да, надо ловить сам Select и получил я обьект CourseLocation как и отправлял. Единственное что смущает, в Select на странице автоматически стало выбираться не первое значение а последнее по списку

Comment: Устранил проблему. Когда сам пробовал написать по другим мануалам не понимая сути, напихал много лишнего кода, он и мешал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак отвечаю сам. Данная задача как и сказал Sergey действительно тривиальна, если понимать принцип работы Select.

1. Select сам определяет какой option был выбран на странице без дополнительных манипуляций. 
   Он забирает значение value="val" у выбранного option
2. Для того чтобы Select отправил значение на сервер, мы должны дать ему параметр name="n". На сервере в сервлете как раз ловим  "n" который хранит в себе "val" выбранного пункта выпадающего меню.
3. Использование скриптов или дополнительных скрытых полей или других сложностей, для конкретно данного случая - передачи выбранного значения, не требуется.

   ```
     <select class="selectpicker" id ="loc" name ="loc">
     <c:forEach items="<%=CourseLocation.values()%>" var="location">
     <option value = "${location}">${location}</option>
     </c:forEach>
     </select>
   ```

В моем конкретном примере использовался jstl и выбор я делал среди объектов Enum. Если кто то решает точно такую же задачу, и решит воспользоваться моим примером, не забудьте передать класс вашего Enum в страницу через

```
 HEAD  <%@ page import="enum" %> /HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью JavaScript можно получить значение (value) выбранного в данный момент option:

```
document.getElementById('loc').value
```

И затем через JavaScript нужно самому отсылать запрос с данными на сервер с помощью Ajax / xmlhttprequest.